# How can I add an image in place of a hamburger menu?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to add a really cool hamburger menu that I found online to my website, but I was wondering if instead using the hamburger menu icon, I could use a circular logo instead that would cover the whole circular hamburger menu button.  I hope this is not a daunting task.

I wanted to use the menu because the author is allowing others to freely use it.

Any feedback is much appreciated!  Thanks!

Here is the link to the source code and menu preview:
https://codepen.io/jasperlachance/pen/yOJdRr

And here is the source code itself:

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
    <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="lines line-1"></span>
    <span class="lines line-2"></span>
    <span class="lines line-3"></span>
</label>

   <a href="#" class="menu-item blue"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item green"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item red"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item purple"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item orange"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item lightblue"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #596778;
color: #EEEEEE;
text-align: center;
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 body {
 padding: 170px 0 0 0;
 width: 100%
 }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.menu-item,
.menu-open-button {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   border-radius: 100%;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: -40px;
   position: absolute;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 80px;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
display: none;
}

.lines {
   width: 25px;
   height: 3px;
   background: #596778;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -12.5px;
   margin-top: -1.5px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.line-2 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-1 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-2 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-3 {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 26px;
}


/* .menu-item {
   transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
} */

.menu-item:hover {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   color: #3290B1;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
-webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
transition-duration: 180ms;
 }

.menu-open-button {
   z-index: 2;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
   transition-duration: 400ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
   transition-duration: 200ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
   transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
   transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
}

.blue {
   background-color: #669AE1;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.blue:hover {
   color: #669AE1;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.green {
   background-color: #70CC72;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.green:hover {
   color: #70CC72;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.red {
   background-color: #FE4365;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.red:hover {
   color: #FE4365;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.purple {
   background-color: #C49CDE;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.purple:hover {
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.orange {
   background-color: #FC913A;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.orange:hover {
   color: #FC913A;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.lightblue {
   background-color: #62C2E4;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.lightblue:hover {
   color: #62C2E4;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.credit {
   margin: 24px 20px 120px 0;
   text-align: right;
   color: #EEEEEE;
}

.credit a {
   padding: 8px 0;
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.credit a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `img` tag inside of your `label` element.

[CodePen Demo Link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgVpJO)

Please look below code-

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #596778;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  body {
    padding: 170px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%
  }
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

.menu-item,
.menu-open-button {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.lines {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #596778;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button .line-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 26px;
}


/* .menu-item {
   transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
} */

.menu-item:hover {
  background: #EEEEEE;
  color: #3290B1;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
  transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-duration: 180ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-duration: 280ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-duration: 380ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-duration: 480ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-duration: 580ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 580ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  transition-duration: 680ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 680ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  transition-duration: 780ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 780ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
}

.blue {
  background-color: #669AE1;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.blue:hover {
  color: #669AE1;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: #70CC72;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.green:hover {
  color: #70CC72;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.red {
  background-color: #FE4365;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.red:hover {
  color: #FE4365;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #C49CDE;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.purple:hover {
  color: #C49CDE;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #FC913A;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.orange:hover {
  color: #FC913A;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: #62C2E4;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.lightblue:hover {
  color: #62C2E4;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.credit {
  margin: 24px 20px 120px 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #EEEEEE;
}

.credit a {
  padding: 8px 0;
  color: #C49CDE;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.credit a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <img src="https://icons-for-free.com/free-icons/png/512/940993.png" width="100%" alt="menu-logo" />
</label>

  <a href="#" class="menu-item blue"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item green"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item red"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item purple"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item orange"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item lightblue"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback!  This was really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure @SteveM .

Answer (score 0):

**please add img tag inside label**

for e.g

```
<label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
      <img  class="menu-open-button" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-dJsZZcc5bgM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABVo/BauAeL0G2iY/photo.jpg?sz=48" />
  </label>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding and providing feedback.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace following html:

```
    <span class="lines line-1"></span>
    <span class="lines line-2"></span>
    <span class="lines line-3"></span>
```

With:

```
<img src="YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_OR_URL" alt="image"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide me with feedback.  I appreciate your input.  Thanks so much!